# What are the differences between versions 1 and 2 of STRAVA API and how to get "streams" objects with v2?

Tags: url, asp.net-web-api

I am currently tinkering with [STRAVA](http://www.strava.com/) API (Strava is a site for logging, sharing and comparing GPS tracklogs taken during cycling and running activities).

In order to get the streams (sample logs) of an activity like this:

```
http://www.strava.com/rides/9999
```

one can use the Version 1 of the API like this:

```
http://www.strava.com/api/v1/streams/9999
```

which returns a `json` string with time-series of speed, position, heartrate, etc.

My problems are:

1. Is there a way to get streams using API v2?
2. Where is the documentation for API v1?

Docs for API v2 are [here](https://stravasite-main.pbworks.com/w/browse/#view=ViewFolderNewGuiGallery&param=Strava%20API%20Documentation)

I've read somewhere that there are differences between POST and GET methods of the API, and that some data require authentication, but I am still (yet more) confused...

Thanks for any help!

---

UPDATE:
For anyone arriving here, as for end of 2013 Strava has (not) released their rather closed V3 API, and shut down their V1 and V2 endpoints.

However, it's still possible to get the JSON streams of a given activity with URLs like these (using activity of Id 9999 as a working example):

http://app.strava.com/stream/9999

http://app.strava.com/activities/9999/streams

Comment: You are far, far more likely to get support by asking the vendor for assistance and/or for documentation improvements.

Comment: I know, but that's a lot like the reason why there are so many questions and tags regarding Google API, Android API, Facebook API, and many other "abundantly documented" APIs, here on SO.

Comment: Just as a comment for anyone who has deleted the just-created the strava tag, something tells me that it will come back to haunt very soon (although I will not be the one to do that).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be aware that these APIs are being deprecated.  [Here](https://stravasite-main.pbworks.com/w/page/58294698/!Sign-up%20for%20new%20API%20notification) is link to both versions of the API documentation, and a place to sign up for notification about the new API coming in early 2013.

You will find that the REST style is only loosely followed for these versions of the API, thus your confusion is understandable.  The new API follows the REST style much more rigorously.  For V1 and V2 GET of a resource will usually return an the object representing that resource in json format.  However there are cases where POST returns the object rather than creating one.  Streams are not returned by the V2 API, only V1. IHTH

Comment: Great answer, specially because of the link. I have now at last a good reason to study the differences between REST, GET and POST (still ignorant about this).